# How to create a carousel in React.js and Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, flexbox, carousel, framer-motion

I want to create an animated carousel with Framer Motion in React.js.
The idea is to see the two divs changing horizontally after each other when a button is clicked.

When I do that with `AnimatePresence`, the first div shrinks, because the second div is created at the same time.
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/carousel-nc4m2?file=/src/App.js) you can see the code sandbox.

I tried already to use `exitBeforeEnter` prop but it doesn't work for my use case. I want to see the two changing divs together. With exitBeforeEnter, this is not possible.

I also tried to set the position of the `Slide` component to `absolute`. The problem with that is, that all the flex properties of the container get lost. The container doesn't adapt it's high depending on the `Slide` component.

How can I do it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it using a grid:

```
      <div
        class="container"
        style={{
          height: 400,
          display: "grid"
        }}
      >

    ...

    <motion.div
      style={{
        gridArea: "1 / 1 / 2 / 2",
        ...
      }}
    >
```